# Connect to MongoDB config server for Sharding on a docker container running on windows10

Tags: mongodb, docker, windows-10

1. I am using `Windows 10` Operating system.
2. I have `Docker for windows` installed on my machine.
3. I have `mongo shell` for Windows installed on my machine.
4. I am creating the config servers using the latest `mongo` image from docker.

I am trying to create config servers (in a replica set; one primary and two secondaries) in order to set up Sharding for MongoDB. I am able to connect to the mongod servers if I create them as replica sets, without specifying the `--configsvr` parameter. But when I specify the `--configsvr` parameter, it fails with below error -

> connecting to:
> mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
> Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt
> failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused
> by :: No connection could be ma de because the target machine actively
> refused it. : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17 @(connect):2:6
> exception: connect failed exiting with code 1

**Case 1 - Creating 3 mongod servers as a replica set**

*Step 1:- Creating 3 mongod containers asia, america and europe.*

```
C:\> docker run -d -p 40001:27017 -v C:/mongodata/data/db --name asia mongo mongod --bind_ip=0.0.0.0 --replSet "rs0"
C:\> docker run -d -p 40002:27017 -v C:/mongodata/data/db --name europe mongo mongod --bind_ip=0.0.0.0 --replSet "rs0"
C:\> docker run -d -p 40003:27017 -v C:/mongodata/data/db --name america mongo mongod --bind_ip=0.0.0.0 --replSet "rs0"
```

*Step 2:- Execute `docker ps`*
[image]

*Step 3:- Using `docker exec` to connect to container named asia.*

```
C:\> docker exec -it asia mongo
```

*RESULT:- Successfully connected*
[image]

*Step 4:-Connecting to the container asia from mongoshell:-*
[image]

**Case 2 - Creating 3 mongod servers as config servers as part of a replica set**

*Step 1:- Creating 3 mongod containers asiaCS, americaCS and europeCS as config servers.*

```
C:/> docker run -d -p 30001:27017 -v C:/mongodata/data/db --name asiaCS mongo mongod --configsvr --bind_ip=0.0.0.0 --replSet "rs1"
C:/> docker run -d -p 30002:27017 -v C:/mongodata/data/db --name europeCS mongo mongod --configsvr --bind_ip=0.0.0.0 --replSet "rs1"
C:/> docker run -d -p 30003:27017 -v C:/mongodata/data/db --name americaCS mongo mongod --configsvr --bind_ip=0.0.0.0 --replSet "rs1"
```

*Step 2:- Execute `docker ps`*
[image]

*Step 3:- Using `docker exec` to connect to container named asiaCS.*

```
docker exec -it asiaCS mongo
```

*RESULT:- Failed to connect*
[image]

*Step 4:-Connecting to the container asiaCS from mongoshell:-*
[image]

The only difference here is the `--configsvr` parameter required to start a mongod instance as a config server for MongoDB sharding. Has anyone encountered such an issue before.

P.S. - I have kept the bind_ip to 0.0.0.0 just to test connection from mongoshell, but tread with caution when doing the same for Production on non-local instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 27019 for config servers.

When you add --configsvr you need to change port mapping too:

C:/> docker run -d -p 30001:**27019** -v C:/mongodata/data/db --name asiaCS mongo mongod **--configsvr** --bind_ip=0.0.0.0 --replSet "rs1"

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Alex. But I still get the same error. And the peculiar thing is `docker exec` is still trying to connect through 127.0.0.1:27017. `docker ps` shows `27017/tcp, 0.0.0.0:30001->27019/tcp` under the PORTS column.

Comment: You need to specify port in `docker exec -it asiaCS mongo --port 27019`  too.

Comment: Please consider https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M103/ It may answer your other question and likely few more that you didn't ask yet. Without shrading part it  can be completed within a day or two. They are free yet quite professionally made, very easy to comprehend