# Connect to MongoDB query router for Sharding on a docker container running on windows10

Tags: mongodb, docker, windows-10

This is a follow up of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67620803/connect-to-mongodb-config-server-for-sharding-on-a-docker-container-running-on-w). [Alex Blex's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67620803/connect-to-mongodb-config-server-for-sharding-on-a-docker-container-running-on-w/67621485#67621485) for connecting to the config servers works great. But I am facing the same issue while connecting to the MongoDB Query router.

Below is the command I am using to create the mongos server

```
docker run -d -p 40001:27017 -v C:/mongodata/data/db --name QR mongo mongos --configdb rs1/172.30.35.165:30001,172.30.32.73:30002,172.30.42.189:30003 --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 --port 27017
```

But I get the below error on executing `docker exec -it QR mongo -port 27017`:-

> connecting to:
> mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
> Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt
> failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused
> by :: No connection could be ma de because the target machine actively
> refused it. : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17 @(connect):2:6
> exception: connect failed exiting with code 1

Below is the replication configuration details for the Config Servers -

```
config = {
          "_id": "rs1",
          "configsvr": true,
          "members":
            [
                {
                "_id": 0,
                "host": "6ed1d953f979:27019"
                },
                {
                "_id": 1,
                "host": "086f0ef5c955:27019"
                },
                {
                "_id": 2,
                "host": "391c9c07b341:27019"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Here is the container ID and IP address

```
------------------------------------------
Server      IP Address      Container ID 
------------------------------------------
asiaCS      172.30.35.165   6ed1d953f979
europeCS    172.30.32.73    086f0ef5c955
americaCS   172.30.42.189   391c9c07b341
```

I am not sure if I am even configuring the mongos properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this one out. Apparently config servers are light weight and do not store any data. Hence, we do not require to bind it to a volume. I first bound all the config servers to a fixed IP (so that docker doesn't assign them a new IP every time I stop and start a container). But for the sake of this answer, I will be using the IPs mentioned in the question itself. I used the below command to create a query router.

```
docker run -d -p 40001:27017 --name QR --hostname QR mongo mongos --configdb "rs1/172.30.35.165:30001,172.30.32.73:30002,172.30.42.189:30003" --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
```

Then docker exec'd into the container by running `docker exec -it QR mongo`

Now while connecting to mongos, if it throws a connection refused error (the one mentioned in the question), you could use the following command -

```
docker exec -it QR mongos --configdb "rs1/172.30.35.165:30001,172.30.32.73:30002,172.30.42.189:30003"
```

The above command will start the mongos without the detached mode and logs will start appearing on your `CMD` or `PowerShell` (whichever way you are running the command) console.

I have mongo shell on my local and I opened another `CMD` prompt and executed the below command -

```
C:\MongoShell\bin> mongosh --host IpAddressOfMongos --port 27017
```

And voila, it connected successfully. You can then close the initial console where you were running docker exec command in attached mode.

IP Address of the mongos can be found out by doing `docker inspect QR`.